# Android Studio Edit Configurations doesn't display my app

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to run my app, but the run button is disabled. When I go in Edit Configurations where I should see "Android Application-->app" I only see the Defaults. Everything was fine 2 hours ago, but I kept working on my project and when I wanted to test it I noticed that I can't. What may have caused this and how do I solve it? I tried to search for a solution, but I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close any emulator if open and then reopen your project, maybe it shows.

Comment: yeah... feel so stupid for not trying that. I modified gradle and the manifest so many times and synced the project, rebuild it etc. Seems that closing and reopening solves the problem. Thanks